# Can I get the dependency tree of all sub-projects using Gradle?

Tags: android, gradle

When in the root directory of my Android project within the terminal, I expected `gradle dependencies` to produce a tree  with the sub-projects included - but this is not the case.

Is it possible to produce this from the root directory? I don't want to keep going into the sub-projects to get the individual trees.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`dependencies` is a special built-in task, and it doesn't seem possible to execute it for all projects at once.

EDIT: I found a way:

```
task allDependencies {
    dependsOn allprojects.collect { "$it.path:dependencies" }
}
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you for continuing to look into this - it is greatly appreciated :D

Comment: Any idea how could we pass arguments to the separately invoked `dependencies`?