# Can't find an easy way to list all dependencies of a gradle project if it contains multi projects

Tags: gradle, dependencies

For a gradle project with multiple sub-projects, if I use:

```
gradle dependencies
```

Which can only list the dependencies of root project.

If I want to list all dependencies, I have to use `gradle projects` to show all sub projects, and then:

```
gradle :someproject:dependencies
```

to view them one by one.

Which is very inconvenient, is there any easy way to do it?

Comment: As far as I know there's is no easy way. Probably you need to implement a custom task.

Comment: Such a basic task, but missing. Gradle brings unexpected complexity.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I get the dependency tree of all sub-projects using Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25450711/can-i-get-the-dependency-tree-of-all-sub-projects-using-gradle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the following task in your root project:

```
task allDependencies {
    doLast() {
        subprojects.each { p->
            println "Showing dependencies of ${p}"
            p.tasks.getByName("dependencies").execute()
        }
    }
}
```

I first tried to call all `dependencies` via `dependsOn`, to avoid calling the `execute()` method, but the following script

```
task allDependencies { 
}
allprojects {
    rootProject.allDependencies.dependsOn(tasks.getByName("dependencies"))
}
```

failed with

> Task with name 'dependencies' not found in project :Foo

Comment: > Could not find method execute() for arguments [] on task ':myModule:dependencies' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.diagnostics.DependencyReportTask.