# How to print out all dependencies in a Gradle multi-project build?

Tags: gradle, dependency-management

I have a Gradle multi-project build with a master-directory where common definitions are located and some projects that are defined in settings.gradle via `include` statements.

Building, testing, runnings all works fine, but showing dependencies via task `dependencies` does not work, it only prints:

```
$ g dependencies
master
:dependencies

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

No configurations

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Doing `gradle :project1:dependencies` in the master-directory works as expected.

How can I get Gradle to print out the whole dependency tree including all the third party libraries for all the projects that are included?

Comment: Such a basic functionality is missing in Gradle! And this runs much deeper - you can program more complex builds, but you get less out of the box.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I get the dependency tree of all sub-projects using Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25450711/can-i-get-the-dependency-tree-of-all-sub-projects-using-gradle)

Answer (score 25):

Unfortunately, you have to specify your own task:

```
allprojects {
    task printAllDependencies(type: DependencyReportTask) {}
}
```

And after that, execute: `./gradlew printAllDependencies`. 

In case if you don't want to see dependencies for the root project, put this task to the `subprojects` block.

```
subprojects {
    task printSubDependencies(type: DependencyReportTask) {}
}
```

---

Suppose you need it to find a certain dependency. In this case, you can use the power of the `dependencyInsight` task.

```
subprojects {
    task findDependency(type: DependencyInsightReportTask) {}
}
```

And after that run

```
./gradlew findDependency --configuration compile --dependency spring-data-jpa
```

Comment: A small update for the answer.
Gradle Build Scan could be a better and more visually-rich option to examine your dependencies: https://scans.gradle.com/#gradle
Just run `gradle build --scan` and follow the steps.

Answer (score 8):

What about next task, where we can create a custom task and apply it for all projects and make it dependant on `dependencies` task. Here is an example:

```
allprojects { currProject ->
    task printDependencies {
        dependsOn 'dependencies'
    }
}
```

Then we can use `./gradlew printDependencies` to print all dependencies from all modules.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know any built-in tasks for that. You may want to make a custom task, like this one:

```
task ('showAll') {
doLast {
   allprojects.each {
       println(it.name+':')
       println('-compile:')
        configurations.compile.each {
            c ->
             println('   '+c.name)
        }
       println '-testCompile:'
       configurations.testCompile.each {
           r->
           println('   '+ r.name)
       }
    }
}
}
```

Output from my project:

```
:showAll
Tools:
-compile:
   groovy-all-2.4.9.jar
   commons-lang3-3.5.jar
   commons-io-2.5.jar
   commons-collections4-4.1.jar
   jsoup-1.10.2.jar
-testCompile:
   groovy-all-2.4.9.jar
   commons-lang3-3.5.jar
   commons-io-2.5.jar
   commons-collections4-4.1.jar
   jsoup-1.10.2.jar
   junit-4.11.jar
   hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
Accounting:
-compile:
   groovy-all-2.4.9.jar
   commons-lang3-3.5.jar
   commons-io-2.5.jar
   commons-collections4-4.1.jar
   jsoup-1.10.2.jar
-testCompile:
   groovy-all-2.4.9.jar
   commons-lang3-3.5.jar
   commons-io-2.5.jar
   commons-collections4-4.1.jar
   jsoup-1.10.2.jar
   junit-4.11.jar
   hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
Jace:
-compile:
   groovy-all-2.4.9.jar
   commons-lang3-3.5.jar
   commons-io-2.5.jar
   commons-collections4-4.1.jar
   jsoup-1.10.2.jar
-testCompile:
   groovy-all-2.4.9.jar
   commons-lang3-3.5.jar
   commons-io-2.5.jar
   commons-collections4-4.1.jar
   jsoup-1.10.2.jar
   junit-4.11.jar
   hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
Bash:
-compile:
   groovy-all-2.4.9.jar
   commons-lang3-3.5.jar
   commons-io-2.5.jar
   commons-collections4-4.1.jar
   jsoup-1.10.2.jar
-testCompile:
   groovy-all-2.4.9.jar
   commons-lang3-3.5.jar
   commons-io-2.5.jar
   commons-collections4-4.1.jar
   jsoup-1.10.2.jar
   junit-4.11.jar
   hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
CSS:
-compile:
   groovy-all-2.4.9.jar
   commons-lang3-3.5.jar
   commons-io-2.5.jar
   commons-collections4-4.1.jar
   jsoup-1.10.2.jar
-testCompile:
   groovy-all-2.4.9.jar
   commons-lang3-3.5.jar
   commons-io-2.5.jar
   commons-collections4-4.1.jar
   jsoup-1.10.2.jar
   junit-4.11.jar
   hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
FXCSS:
-compile:
   groovy-all-2.4.9.jar
   commons-lang3-3.5.jar
   commons-io-2.5.jar
   commons-collections4-4.1.jar
   jsoup-1.10.2.jar
-testCompile:
   groovy-all-2.4.9.jar
   commons-lang3-3.5.jar
   commons-io-2.5.jar
   commons-collections4-4.1.jar
   jsoup-1.10.2.jar
   junit-4.11.jar
   hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
Gradle:
-compile:
   groovy-all-2.4.9.jar
   commons-lang3-3.5.jar
   commons-io-2.5.jar
   commons-collections4-4.1.jar
   jsoup-1.10.2.jar
-testCompile:
   groovy-all-2.4.9.jar
   commons-lang3-3.5.jar
   commons-io-2.5.jar
   commons-collections4-4.1.jar
   jsoup-1.10.2.jar
   junit-4.11.jar
   hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
Groovy:
-compile:
   groovy-all-2.4.9.jar
   commons-lang3-3.5.jar
   commons-io-2.5.jar
   commons-collections4-4.1.jar
   jsoup-1.10.2.jar
-testCompile:
   groovy-all-2.4.9.jar
   commons-lang3-3.5.jar
   commons-io-2.5.jar
   commons-collections4-4.1.jar
   jsoup-1.10.2.jar
   junit-4.11.jar
   hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
HTML:
-compile:
   groovy-all-2.4.9.jar
   commons-lang3-3.5.jar
   commons-io-2.5.jar
   commons-collections4-4.1.jar
   jsoup-1.10.2.jar
-testCompile:
   groovy-all-2.4.9.jar
   commons-lang3-3.5.jar
   commons-io-2.5.jar
   commons-collections4-4.1.jar
   jsoup-1.10.2.jar
   junit-4.11.jar
   hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
Java:
-compile:
   groovy-all-2.4.9.jar
   commons-lang3-3.5.jar
   commons-io-2.5.jar
   commons-collections4-4.1.jar
   jsoup-1.10.2.jar
-testCompile:
   groovy-all-2.4.9.jar
   commons-lang3-3.5.jar
   commons-io-2.5.jar
   commons-collections4-4.1.jar
   jsoup-1.10.2.jar
   junit-4.11.jar
   hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
Text:
-compile:
   groovy-all-2.4.9.jar
   commons-lang3-3.5.jar
   commons-io-2.5.jar
   commons-collections4-4.1.jar
   jsoup-1.10.2.jar
-testCompile:
   groovy-all-2.4.9.jar
   commons-lang3-3.5.jar
   commons-io-2.5.jar
   commons-collections4-4.1.jar
   jsoup-1.10.2.jar
   junit-4.11.jar
   hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately that does not include the transitive dependencies, but usually I am trying to find a problem where transitive dependencies drag in stuff that I do not want to have...

Answer (score 0):

or with the kotlin DSL:

```
allprojects {
    tasks.register("printAllDependencies",DependencyReportTask::class) {}
}
```