# How do I lock dependencies in gradle 6.7.1?

Tags: java, gradle, dependency-management

I was reading the [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_locking.html) for dependency locking in gradle. I put the following incantation in my `deps.gradle` file and versions are still sliding around.

```
dependencyLocking {
  lockAllConfigurations()
}
```

I then noticed the caveat "The above will lock all project configurations, but not the buildscript ones" but I could not find docs that explained the difference.

**What is the difference and how can I lock all dependencies?**

Note that I'm aware of one other way of locking depenencies that does seem to work, but it seems very verbose so I'd like to avoid it if possible:

```
  implementation('com.github.jnr:jffi') {
    version {
       strictly '1.2.23'
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 7):

```
lockAllConfigurations()
```

only makes all of you configurations **eligible** for dependency locking. It does not automatically lock the dependencies. Otherwise the dynamic version will become useless and you can simply specify the exact version number when adding dependencies.

To actually produce the dependency lock file, you need to pass --write-locks to gradle when running a task, e.g.:

```
gradle dependencies --write-locks
```

See [this part](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_locking.html#generating_and_updating_dependency_locks) of the documentation.

Comment: `./gradlew dependencies --write-locks` didn't work for my multi-module project. Instead, I had to define a task to call `dependencies` on all of my modules.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44338880/9636

Comment: Of course. Gradle tasks are executed in the current project context, and in a multi-module build,  tasks in each sub module will have to be prefixed in order to be directly invoked. If you read the doc, the doc never says dependencies is the task to lock your dependencies. Any task that results in dependency resolution will do the job. And if you have a multi-module build, any task that results in dependency resolution of all the modules will work (i.e. try build).