# Could not find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.6.1

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

I follow the instructions [here](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.springframework.boot) for the latest `spring.framework.boot` plugin.

My `build.gradle` has

```
plugins {
  id 'java-library'
  id 'eclipse'
  id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
  id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.2'
  id 'org.springframework.boot.experimental.thin-launcher' version '1.0.23.RELEASE'
}
```

but gradle tasks have the error

```
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':detachedConfiguration1'.
   > Could not find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.6.2.
```

*UPDATE* I neglected to add the final lines of the error description, which were in fact important to answer it.

```
 Searched in the following locations:
   - https://repo.spring.io/snapshot/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.6.2/spring-boot-dependencies-2.6.2.pom
   - https://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.6.2/spring-boot-dependencies-2.6.2.pom
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @granadaCoder above, and after reinstalling Gradle to the latest version `7.3.3` the actual problem was that a 2nd repositories setting had crept into my `build.gradle`

```
repositories {
  maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
  maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}
```

Which was exactly where the error said the dependencies were not found. I changed this to

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}
```

Things then started to work.

Comment: SOF etiquette is ... that "after you figure it out", you mark one of the answers as "The Answer" to stop this question coming up as "un-answered".

Comment: And that is why I think it is a better best practice to provide "full" contents.....but for my answer..but also for your initial question.   #lessonsLearned        Outside of this question, it drives me nuts when java developers do not put in import statements on both answers and questions.

Comment: Yes, I didn't give the full error description and deserve to be marked down :-( Question is now updated.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a FULL file as an example: (this is the ROOT build.gradle) (If you code a monolith, you'll only have a root build.gradle, if you write multiple "gradle modules", you'll have a root and subproject build.gradle files) (if you have no idea what i'm talking about see link to docs.gradle.org at bottom)

(you can remove the dependencies, but i prefer to give a full working)

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-ldap'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-integration'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-services'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    implementation 'com.h2database:h2'
    implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'


    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}


allprojects {

    /* custom task to show dependencies.  run "gradle printAllDependencies" from commandline.  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44266687/how-to-print-out-all-dependencies-in-a-gradle-multi-project-build/54436979#54436979 */
    task printAllDependencies(type: DependencyReportTask) {}

}
```

Alternatively, you can try a "gradle FLUSH"

```
Gradle FLUSH Cache
(Optional, but preferred).  Close all instances of IntelliJ or any other Java IDE.

./gradlew --stop        
      OR
gradle --stop

(now delete the folders)

rm -rf $HOME/.gradle/caches/

rm -rf $HOME/.gradle/build-cache-tmp/

(now resume normal gradlew commands like:)

./gradlew clean build
```

and alternatively, you can do an intelliJ "FLUSH"

```
(tested with IntelliJ version 2020.1 or later)
    Close IntelliJ.
    Delete the ".idea" folder off of the root folder.
    Re OPEN the project.
    Wait for Gradle imports and indices rebuild to complete
    Try the IDE build again.

And the big hammer: "Invalidate IntelliJ caches".  see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Cleaning_System_Cache.html and/or https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/invalidate-caches.html
```

If you're using Eclipse or NetBeans or Other, you'll have to find the "equivalent".  The idea is that the IDE gets "confused".

BONUS

Multi Gradle Module :

https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_building_java_applications_multi_project.html